# Defining specific lengths with HTML5 input pattern attributes

Tags: html, input

Right now I can set a specific length, or a range, but not two different lengths, both valid.

pattern="{11}" <-One specific length
pattern="{11,15}" <-Range

How do you get it to accept only 11 or 15 but nothing else? No 12, 13, 14, 5, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern attribute is based on [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). RegEx {} checks for character occurences (in your case 11 and 15).

You can't check for exactly two different (non-adjacent) lengths with one expression and one {} notation.

You would need to write two expressions: the first one checks for 11 characters and the second one for 15 characters. You can chain these two regular expressions with some conditionality. Some [If-else-conditionality](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) exists, but may not be supported by the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with OR statement: `<input pattern="(.{11}|.{15})">`

Comment: This exactly what I was talking about, chaining multiple Reg-expressions with conditionality. And the browser support has got a lot better in last 8 years :)